# Do you think you can do reuse of err variables?

Tags: go

For example, in such cases the err variable will finish its role soon on the spot, so I do not think it is necessary to define multiple names.

```
package main

func main() {
    foo, errFoo := foo()
    if errFoo != nil {
        panic(errFoo)
    }

    bar, errBar := bar()
    if errBar != nil {
        panic(errFoo)
    }
}
```

So I change the code as follows.

```
package main

func main() {
    foo, err := foo()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    bar, err := bar()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

What kind of rules do you guys do?

Comment: If you are asking if it can be done the answer is "yes". If you ask what should be done the answer is opinion based and therefore out of scope.

Comment: For those coming here, after seeing `no new variables on left side of :=`, you cannot redeclare(`:=`) the err variable but can assign(`=`) it a value again. so just replace `bar, err := bar()` with `bar, err = bar()`, which should probably resolve the issue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Its very common to reuse `err` variable especially with the s*hort variable declaration* format.
Mostly when you get an `err` at any point, you handle that and return/panic immediately.

So if you have code like:

```
func foo() error{
   a, err := f1()
   if err != nil{
     return err
   }

   //... do something with a

  //if we are here we know err is nil, so we can reuse it easily without any information getting lost
  b, err := f2()
  if err != nil{
    return err
  }
   //... do something with b

  return nil
}
```

then its very ok to reuse `err`

Comment: What about nested situation? I faced such code: `err = json.Unmarshal(message, &foo)
  if err != nil {
   ...
   dataByte, err = json.Marshal(result)
   if err != nil {
    log.Printf("ERROR: %v\n", err)
   }
  }` And its hard to realize that `err` has another value